# Высота родительского блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый есть простая разметка родительский блок в котором вложена картинка (лишнее убрал):

```
<div class="catalog-layout">
        <div class="catalog-layout__item">
            <img src="img/1_1.png" alt="" class="catalog-layout__item--img">
        </div> 
        <div class="catalog-layout__item">
            <img src="img/1_2.png" alt="" class="catalog-layout__item--img">
        </div>
</div>
<!-- /.catalog-layout -->
```

С минимальными стилями `max-width` для `img`

вопрос в чем: Если родительскому блоку не задавать явные размеры - то он принимает размер содержимого...
Ширина картинок одинаковая, а высота разная.

А выходит так, что блок `.catalog-layout__item` больше по высоте на 4px. чем картинка вложенная в него и никак не могу найти и решить почему так, а эти 4пх портят всю картину...

помогите люди добрые - плохо сплю по ночам)))

[image: блок]

[image: изображение]

Comment: `img { display: block; }`

Comment: @meine тогда же ширина будет на всю доступную

Comment: div по умолчанию имеет ширину 100% родительского блока, в этом случае это вся ширина страницы. насчет вашего вопроса - display: block, т.к. инлайновые элементы имеют такой косяк в виде неприятного промежутка, т.к. в разметке у них учитываются переносы строки (клавишей Enter). ЛИБО. Вы можете в html файле просто "скомкать" ваши блоки, и они отобразятся без этого промежутка. Например: <div class="catalog-layout__item"><img src="img/1_1.png" alt="" class="catalog-layout__item--img"></div><div class="catalog-layout__item"><img src="img/1_2.png" alt="" class="catalog-layout__item--img"></div>

Comment: точно)) спасибо!